# I was cloning youtube to the comment post but I got an error Request failed with status code 401

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

code redux action

```js
export const addComment = (id, text) => async (dispatch, getState) => 
{

    try {
        const obj = {
            snippet: {
                videoId: id,
                topLevelComment: {
                    snippet: {
                        textOriginal: text,
                        videoId: id,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        await request.post('/commentThreads', obj, {
            params: {
                part: 'id, replies, snippet',
                videoId: id,
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${getState().auth.accessToken}`,
            }
        })
        dispatch({
            type: CREATE_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
        })
        setTimeout(() => dispatch(getCommentVideoById(id)), 2000)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        dispatch({
            type: CREATE_COMMENT_FAIL,
            payload: error.message
        })
    }
 }
```

[When I click on the network error, it shows](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=AIzaSyDrlBWMPkEuG0p00kDgWshdaOiFXE1zGZQ&part=snippet&videoId=-vL01jbgENE)

[code component comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chlYe.png)

Is there any way to help me in this case?

I can't post comments,
i have loaded the comment list from the api and got the id, i don't know why because i am a newbie to the api

Comment: Don't post your code as images.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the access token correctly added in the response.

Error 401 means [Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401).

Comment: can you tell in detail how to check,
I'm new to this so a lot of things are not clear